# How to type check use of a python type as a function?

Tags: python, mypy

I am new to using type checking with python, and want to create a function that takes a single value, and either returns `None` if that value is `None`, or returns the result of applying a function to it. It works, but doesn't type check when passing a type as a function, such as `int`.

#### 1st attempt:

```
from typing import Callable, Optional, TypeVar, Union

A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')

def maybe(val: A, fn: Callable[[A], B]) -> Optional[B]:
    if val is not None:
        return fn(val)
    return None

myVar: Optional[Union[str, int]] = "42"
ret = maybe(myVar, int)
```

That appeared to work fine and type check OK when I called `maybe(myVar, myFn)` and `myFn` was a normal function or lambda. However, if I try `maybe(myVar, int)`, then `mypy` complains that `int` has the wrong type:

```
test.py:12: error: Argument 2 to "maybe" has incompatible type "Type[int]"; expected "Callable[[Union[str, int, None]], int]"
```

Although [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) describes `int()` as a built-in function, it actually has the type `<class 'type'>`, so the error kind of makes sense.  However, although the error is raised about the second argument (`int`), `mypy` only complains when the first argument is Optional. If `myVar` is a plain `str` or `int`, it type checks OK.

### 2nd attempt

I tried changing the function signature to accept types as well as callables:

```
from typing import Callable, Optional, Type, TypeVar, Union

A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')

def maybe(val: A, fn: Union[Callable[[A], B], Type[B]]) -> Optional[B]:
    if val is not None:
        return fn(val)
    return None

myVar: Optional[Union[str, int]] = "42"
ret = maybe(myVar, int)
```

That fixed the errors when calling `maybe()`.  Instead, at the line `return fn(val)`, `mypy` gives an error I don't understand:

```
test.py:8: error: Too many arguments for "object"
```

How can I fix this error? Is there a more pythonic way of doing what I want?

#### Versions

```
Python 3.7.7
mypy 0.770
```

Comment: _if I try `maybe(myVar, int)`, then `mypy` complains that `int` has the wrong type_ - [cannot reproduce that with 0.780](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.780&python=3.8&gist=02edc12f62ac83ffa78cd177bbeb049c). Probably `myVar` is not an int, string, bytes or bytearray? `int()` doesn't accept arbitrary objects.

Comment: I've updated my question to demonstrate the problem better. `myVar` was the correct type (`str`), but it seems to be a problem that it is Optional.

Comment: Note that ``maybe`` does *not* pass ``None`` to the ``Callable``. Therefore, the ``Callable`` does *not* take the complete type of ``val``, only the non-optional part. The proper annotation is ``val: Optional[A]``. mypy 0.782 still does not properly process this, though – ``A`` is inferred to be ``object``.

Comment: Using `val: Optional[A]` sounds like it makes sense, so I'll go with that for clarity and ignore the error for now. Any idea if this is something the mypy devs are likely to be working on? I'm not sure if I could describe the problem with enough clarity to make a useful Issue report.